# FLATPAGES_EXTENSION = '.md' seems to be doing absolutely nothing

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-flatpages

I am generating a static website using flask and everything is working as it should apart from one thing.  I am trying to get flask FlatPages to only look for .md files.  The documentation and the rurorials I have found online all say that the solution is to use the `FLATPAGES_EXTENSION = '.md'` but it doesn't seem to work.

If i save the files as .html they seem to act like .md files but the .md files aren't being found.  Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_flatpages import FlatPages
import sys


app = Flask(__name__)
FLATPAGES_EXTENSION = '.md'

pages = FlatPages(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('bloghome.html', pages=pages)

@app.route('/<path:path>.html')
def page(path):
    print("pages running")
    page = pages.get_or_404(path)
    return render_template('page.html', page=page)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

to make this clear, I have four files in my pages folder: first.html, second.html, third.html, fourth.md.

The the only one that isn't recognised is `fourth.md`.  I could just save them as .html since that seems to work but it makes for easier editing if they are .md format.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  I should have been using `app.config['FLATPAGES_EXTENSION'] = '.md'`

Comment: this helped me immensely. thanks!